# Why is this recyclerview only shows 5 items?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, nestedrecyclerview

So this recyclerview somehow only shows 5 items. When I delete the 5th item, the 6th item will comeout, so it seems it can only shows 5 items. Why?

For further information, this recyclerview is using Groupie library. I have used the same code in other activity but this one, each row is much bigger in terms of height because it has more information, does it have to do with the reason why the 6th item cannot be shown? The other recyclerview using groupie only shows name in each row, so it can show up to 7 items so far, only this one, despite using the same code, only shows 5 items maximum.

Following is the recyclerview code:

```js
private fun fetchProducts() {

        databaseReferenceProducts = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("produk")
        databaseReferenceProducts.child(uid).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object: ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                if (snapshot.exists()) {
                    binding.kedaiConstraintLayout.setPadding(0,0,0,0)
                    val adapter = GroupAdapter<GroupieViewHolder>()

                    snapshot.children.forEach {
                        val user = it.getValue(DataProduk::class.java)
                        if (user != null) {
                            binding.daftarProdukRecyclerView.adapter = adapter
                            adapter.add(productItems(user))
                        }
                    }

                    binding.daftarProdukRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(
                        DividerItemDecoration(
                            context,
                            DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL
                        )
                    )


                }
            override fun onCancelled(snapshot: DatabaseError) {
            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: Ain't no RecyclerView code in there chief. Maybe your `getItemCount` implementation returns *5*?

Comment: @cactustictacs thanks, the viewHolder code is provided as well. Just for information, does using Groupie has anything to do with this problem? couldnt find `getItemCount` code is being used yet.

Comment: is `recyclerView` height is `wrap_content` like  `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

Comment: @MansoorMalik yes, you are right, does it need to be changed to something? I have tried to change it to `wrap_content`, `match_parent`, or `0dp` but it still doesnt want to show the 6th item onwards regardless.

Comment: yes make height of `recyclerView`  `wrap_content`

Comment: @MansoorMalik still wont make it shows 6th item onwards though?

Comment: only 5 items ae showing ?when you scroll then 6th item show?

Comment: 6th item and onward wont show up regardless the `layout_height` given

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For whoever facing this kind of issue, this is because the `RecyclerView` is overlapped with `ScrollView`. Replace it with `NestedScrollView` instead.